# Web Part Zone Title shows Untitled[0] in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, web-parts, webpartpage

I have a panel placed inside a webpart which holds a chart . The title of the webpart zone is Untitled[0],Untitled[1]....There is no title tag in the panel control or web part . Any one know how to solve this .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

```
            <asp:WebPartZone Height="100px" Width="75%" runat="server" 
                ID="productSummaryZone" HeaderText="Product summary">
                <ZoneTemplate>
                    <uc:ProductSummary title="Product summary title" runat="server" ID="productSummary" />
                </ZoneTemplate>
            </asp:WebPartZone>
```

- `HeaderText="Product summary"`. This header is used to identify your web part when you are in edit, design mode or connect mode (this is not the title)
- `<uc:ProductSummary title="Product summary title" runat="server" ID="productSummary" />`. This represents a `UserControl` in this case, and this was added in the `ZoneTemplate`, as you can see, you can pass a `title="..."` to your `UserControl` even when you do not have declared a property with that name, the `WebPart` then uses that property to display the title... kinda tricky

Output

[image]